# CSS Scrollbar Issue in Chrome - The scrollbar and the space allocation for it are triggered separately?

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbar

I have a straightforward markup of HTML and CSS. There is a fixed div at 100% width, and 33.3333333% height, positioned to be below the bottom of the page with its top part peeking out. (bottom:-28.21%;) - I am using a Javascript in another version of this code to bring it up fully. (bottom:0;)

It looks fine except for: When the bottom of the main content div is near to/intersects with the bottom of the window. At this point, the 100% width fixed div very oddly shrinks to about 95%. A small space also appears underneath it.

It only happens in Chrome. Has anyone experienced this? Any CSS fixes? Or is it a bug in the browser? (Thats how it seems to me...)

Here is an image http://s12.postimage.org/er7ld88d9/Capture.jpg.

Here is the code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RUMjD/1/)

CSS:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.squareDiv {
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.squareDiv img {
    width: 100%;
}

.bottomBar {
    background-color: red;
    bottom: -28.21%;
    height: 33.333333333%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="midMid">
    <div class="squareDiv"><img src="Watermelons.jpg" class="mainImg" /></div>
    <div class="squareDiv"><img src="Watermelons.jpg" class="mainImg" /></div>
    <div class="squareDiv"><img src="Watermelons.jpg" class="mainImg" /></div>
    <div class="squareDiv"><img src="Watermelons.jpg" class="mainImg" /></div>
    <div class="squareDiv"><img src="Watermelons.jpg" class="mainImg" /></div>
    <div class="squareDiv"><img src="Watermelons.jpg" class="mainImg" /></div>
</div>

<div class="bottomBar">
    <div class="bottomBarTop"></div>
    <div class="bottomBarMain"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: Adding (overflow-y:hidden) to the body patches the issue, but I need those scrollbars when the content exceeds the window height!!